# Error in rpy2- No (non-missing) observations

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I m working with rpy2 on Ubuntu 1104. I m following the [COX](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-cox-regression.pdf) file. The steps given in file are in R. I have to do same steps in python using rpy2. 
I didn't get any tutorial with rpy2. I managed to write following,

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import IntVector, Formula
import rpy2.robjects as ro
cox = importr("survival")
csv = ro.vectors.DataFrame.from_csvfile('Rossi.txt', header=True, sep=' ')
fmla = Formula('Surv(week, arrest) ~ fin + age + race + wexp + mar + paro + prio')
mod_aalison = cox.coxph (fmla, data=csv)
```

But I'm getting following error,

```
>>> mod_aalison = cox.coxph (fmla, data=csv)
Error in function (formula, data, weights, subset, na.action, init, control,  : 
  No (non-missing) observations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 83, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 35, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in function (formula, data, weights, subset, na.action, init, control,  : 
  No (non-missing) observations
```

Am I missing any thing? I have no prior experience on R. 
I'm not sure the if data in function coxph has to be in dataframe format.
Any help is appreciated.

This is link to [Rossi.txt](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/Rossi.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read the data using `read.csv` with sep set to a single space, while the file has two spaces. This makes R interpret this as an existence of empty columns, which then mess with column names and finally create error in `coxph`.

Read the data with `read.table`, and it should be ok.

Comment: Hi mbq, thnks for your ans. It worked and saved me. Also to point out, RPY2 is changing the column names like, **arrest** to **X.arrest.** This should not happen. `>>> print csv.colnames
 [1] "X.week."   "X.arrest." "X.fin."    "X.age."    "X.race."   "X.wexp."  
 [7] "X.mar."    "X.paro."   "X.prio."   "X.educ."   "X.emp1."   "X.emp2."  
[13] "X.emp3."   "X.emp4."   "X.emp5."   "X.emp6."   "X.emp7."   "X.emp8."`

Comment: Me too, I use `X <- cbind(var1,var2, ... varn)` how to solve this?